# Javascript group by object properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects below

```
var inventory = [
    { Name: "KIT001", SerialNo: "K111", Status: "Out For Cleaning", NewStatus: "Cleaned" },
    { Name: "KIT001", SerialNo: "K112", Status: "Out For Cleaning", NewStatus: "Cleaned" },
    { Name: "KIT001", SerialNo: "K113", Status: "Out For Cleaning", NewStatus: "Cleaned" },
    { Name: "KIT001", SerialNo: "K132", Status: "Out For Cleaning", NewStatus: "Need Cleaning" },
    { Name: "KIT001", SerialNo: "K134", Status: "Out For Cleaning", NewStatus: "Need Cleaning" },
];
```

I would like to do a group by "Out For Cleaning" and "Cleaned" in such a way that the end result would return multiple arrays like below:

```
var arr1 = [
    { Name: "KIT001", SerialNo: "K111", Status: "Out For Cleaning", NewStatus: "Cleaned" },
    { Name: "KIT001", SerialNo: "K112", Status: "Out For Cleaning", NewStatus: "Cleaned" },
    { Name: "KIT001", SerialNo: "K113", Status: "Out For Cleaning", NewStatus: "Cleaned" },
];

var arr2 = [
    { Name: "KIT001", SerialNo: "K132", Status: "Out For Cleaning", NewStatus: "Need Cleaning" },
    { Name: "KIT001", SerialNo: "K134", Status: "Out For Cleaning", NewStatus: "Need Cleaning" },
];
```

**UPDATE**

I need to do a group by STATUS first and then NEW_STATUS. Note, that these arrays will be dynamic.

```
var STATUS = ["Out For Cleaning", "Out For Repair"];
var NEW_STATUS = ["Cleaned", "Repaired"];
```

This is what I came up with however, it only groups by the STATUS property.

```
for (var i = 0; i < STATUS.length; i++) {
          var arr1 = inventory.filter(function (el) {
               return el.Status == STATUS[i];
          });

          if(arr1.length > 0)
               console.log('Final Array: ', arr1)              
}
```

Comment: can you use underscore?

Comment: I can't use underscore

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: Split array of objects into seperate arrays with dynamic names depending on property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54008878/javascript-split-array-of-objects-into-seperate-arrays-with-dynamic-names-depen)

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to filter the array:

```
var arr1 = status.filter(function(el) {
    return el.NewStatus == "Cleaned";
});

var arr2 = status.filter(function(el) {
    return el.NewStatus == "Need Cleaning";
});
```

Comment: Your answer helped me get started.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

```
function GroupBy(array){
  var fields = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
  var field = fields.shift();

  if(field){

    var groupedArray = [];
    for(var i in array){
      var index = array[i][field];
      groupedArray[index] = groupedArray[index] || [];
      groupedArray[index].push(array[i]);
    }

    for(var i in groupedArray)
      groupedArray[i] = GroupBy.bind(null, groupedArray[i]).apply(null, fields);

    return groupedArray;
  }

  return array;
}
```

Then use it like this. Group the records by fields:

```
var groupedArray = GroupBy(yourArray, "STATUS", "NEW_STATUS");
```

Then get records by the specified fields:

```
var list = groupedArray["Out For Cleaning"]["Need Cleaning"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < STATUS.length; i++) {

  var arr1 = inventory.filter(function(el) {
      return el.NewStatus == NEW_STATUS[i-1];
      console.log(el.NewStatus);
  });

  document.getElementById("grey").innerHTML =JSON.stringify(arr1);

  var arr2 = inventory.filter(function(el) {
      return el.NewStatus == NEW_STATUS[i];
  });

  document.getElementById("blue").innerHTML =JSON.stringify(arr2);

}
```