# Javascript: Split array of objects into seperate arrays with dynamic names depending on property value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, slice

I have an array containing objects. Now I want to slice the array to new arrays containing only those objects matching a certain property value.

Ideally the new array names should be created dynamically.

The original array looks like this:

```
specificSlotButtonArray = [
  {slotStarttime:"06:00:00", slotTimespan:1},
  {slotStarttime:"09:00:00", slotTimespan:1},
  {slotStarttime:"12:00:00", slotTimespan:2},
  {slotStarttime:"15:00:00", slotTimespan:2},
  {slotStarttime:"18:00:00", slotTimespan:3}
];
```

The new arrays should look like this:

```
timespan1 = [
  {slotStarttime:"06:00:00", slotTimespan:1},
  {slotStarttime:"09:00:00", slotTimespan:1}
]

timespan2 = [
  {slotStarttime:"12:00:00", slotTimespan:2},
  {slotStarttime:"15:00:00", slotTimespan:2}
]

timespan3 = [
  {slotStarttime:"18:00:00", slotTimespan:3}
]
```

If possible, I want to avoid javascript syntax / functions, which are not supported by IE and some other older browsers.

I already tried to work with `reduce()` and `slice()`, but did not find a solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can simply achieve your desired outcome using `reduce`, as you can produce an object using `reduce`, here's an example of how you could do it.

As you can see, it'll check that the relevant property on the object isn't null, if it is, then it's set to an empty array, after this check, it's safe to simply push the relevant values onto the array, like so.

```js
var array = [{
    slotStarttime: "06:00:00",
    slotTimespan: 1
  },
  {
    slotStarttime: "09:00:00",
    slotTimespan: 1
  },
  {
    slotStarttime: "12:00:00",
    slotTimespan: 2
  },
  {
    slotStarttime: "15:00:00",
    slotTimespan: 2
  },
  {
    slotStarttime: "18:00:00",
    slotTimespan: 3
  }
];

var newObject = array.reduce(function(obj, value) {
  var key = `timespan${value.slotTimespan}`;
  if (obj[key] == null) obj[key] = [];

  obj[key].push(value);
  return obj;
}, {});

console.log(newObject);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a generic group by key reducer. I will take it from a [previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53320017/partial-lenses-group-array-of-objects-by-property-use-prop-value-as-key/53320615#53320615). It is an elegant and simple way to generate a function that group your data by a particular key that comes as an argument.

```js
const groupBy = key => (result,current) => {
  const item = Object.assign({},current);
  if (typeof result[current[key]] == 'undefined'){
    result[current[key]] = [item];
  }else{
    result[current[key]].push(item);
  }
  return result;
};

const specificSlotButtonArray = [
  {slotStarttime:"06:00:00", slotTimespan:1},
  {slotStarttime:"09:00:00", slotTimespan:1},
  {slotStarttime:"12:00:00", slotTimespan:2},
  {slotStarttime:"15:00:00", slotTimespan:2},
  {slotStarttime:"18:00:00", slotTimespan:3}
];

const timespan = specificSlotButtonArray.reduce(groupBy('slotTimespan'),{});
console.log(timespan);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could reduce the array by taking an object for the part arrays.

```js
var specificSlotButtonArray = [{ slotStarttime: "06:00:00", slotTimespan: 1 }, { slotStarttime: "09:00:00", slotTimespan: 1 }, { slotStarttime: "12:00:00", slotTimespan: 2 }, { slotStarttime: "15:00:00", slotTimespan: 2 }, { slotStarttime: "18:00:00", slotTimespan: 3 }],
    timespan1 = [],
    timespan2 = [],
    timespan3 = [];
    
specificSlotButtonArray.reduce(function (r, o) {
    r[o.slotTimespan].push(o);
    return r;
}, { 1: timespan1, 2: timespan2, 3: timespan3 });

console.log(timespan1);
console.log(timespan2);
console.log(timespan3);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The following soluce iterates once on `specificSlotButtonArray` using `Array.reduce`. This soluce will adapt to any number of `slotTimespan`.

```js
const specificSlotButtonArray = [{
    slotStarttime: '06:00:00',
    slotTimespan: 1,
  },
  {
    slotStarttime: '09:00:00',
    slotTimespan: 1,
  },
  {
    slotStarttime: '12:00:00',
    slotTimespan: 2,
  },
  {
    slotStarttime: '15:00:00',
    slotTimespan: 2,
  },
  {
    slotStarttime: '18:00:00',
    slotTimespan: 3,
  },
];

// Loop through the array
const splitted = specificSlotButtonArray.reduce((tmp, x) => {
  // Look if we got already an array having the slotTimespan of the current
  // item to treat
  const match = tmp.find(y => y.some(z => z.slotTimespan === x.slotTimespan));

  // If we have such array, push the data into it
  if (match) {
    match.push(x);
  } else {
    // If we don't create a new array
    tmp.push([x]);
  }

  return tmp;
}, []);

console.log(splitted);
```

If you want to deals with the array straight after the `Array.reduce` you can use destructuration :

```
const [
  timespan1,
  timespan2,
  timespan3
] = specificSlotButtonArray.reduce((tmp, x) => {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to create separate arrays grouped by `slotTimespan`,

```js
    specificSlotButtonArray = [
        {slotStarttime:"06:00:00", slotTimespan:1},
        {slotStarttime:"09:00:00", slotTimespan:1},
        {slotStarttime:"12:00:00", slotTimespan:2},
        {slotStarttime:"15:00:00", slotTimespan:2},
        {slotStarttime:"18:00:00", slotTimespan:3}
    ];
    
    function groupBy(arr, property) {
        return arr.reduce(function(memo, x) {
            if (!memo[x[property]]) { memo[x[property]] = []; }
            memo[x[property]].push(x);
            return memo;
        }, {});
    }
    
    console.log(groupBy(specificSlotButtonArray, "slotTimespan"));
```